# Dokku shows old site after deploy

Tags: angularjs, dokku

I have a dokku server running at my university. 
After changing a few things on the Website (adding Buttons) and successfully deploying to Dokku, it still shows the old Build.

I tried redeploying, I completely rebooted the server, it's always the old build.

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid, i'm sorry. Chrome on my computer used the cached version of the site. Deleting Chromes Cache fixed it.